# dynamical textbox and autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

i want to make autocomplete in my dynamical textboxes. i already tried every way but it didn't work.
here is my autocomplete.php code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rbmv3") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch department names from the department table
$sql = "select country_name from countries";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

$dname_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dname_list[] = $row['country_name'];
}
echo json_encode($dname_list);?>
```

and here is my index.php code:

```
<label>Department Name</label></br>
<button type="button"  onclick="coba()"> Tes </button> <br>
<div id="add">
<input class="department_name" type="text" size="50" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
$(".department_name").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus:true
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function coba(){
            document.getElementById("add").innerHTML +=
   " <inputclass='department_name' type='text' size='50' />";
    }
</script>
```

when i tried the autocomplete code into one textbox or many textboxes without dynamically added, it works well. anyone can help me solved this problem?

Comment: You may need to call `autoComplete()` function on new added elements too so as to  bind the plugin functionality.

Comment: Can you just help me to rewrite my index code? Thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: how can i call autoComplete() function in my new added elements? @Developer107

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the current binding of auto complete using `destroy()` and again call `autoComplete()`

```
function coba(){
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML +=
    " <inputclass='department_name' type='text' size='50' />";
    $(".department_name").autocomplete( "destroy" );
    $(".department_name").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus:true
    });
}
```

Comment: Even if i use destroy() my autocomplete in previous textbox still working or not? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @JulianaSucahya did you use `.autocomplete( "destroy" );`? Please see - https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-destroy

Comment: @JulianaSucahya After you are using `destroy()` then you are again binding. So it will work

Comment: I haven't tried that. I'll tell you guys after i try it. Thanks :)

Comment: @JulianaSucahya Can you replicate the issue and provide a demo?